# react.js: call a function from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I come from vue.js, so I'm still a bit confused about react.

I have a Message component, that shows up flash messages:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

export default class Message extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {messages: []};
    }

    setMessage(type, body) {
        this.setState({messages: this.state.messages.concat({type: type, body: body})})
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.removeMessage()
        }, 10000);
    }

    removeMessage() {
        let messages = this.state.messages;
        messages.shift();
        this.setState({messages: messages});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="uk-messages">
                {
                    this.state.messages.map((message, index) => {
                        if (message.type === 'error') {
                            message.type = 'danger';
                        }

                        return (
                            <div className={'uk-alert-' + message.type} data-uk-alert key={index}>
                                <p>{message.body}</p>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )    
    }    
}
```

I use this component in my Index component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
import Auth from './helpers/auth'
import Message from './helpers/message'

class Index extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            authState: Auth.state,
        };
        Auth.initialize();    
    }

    render() {
        return (    
            <Router>
                <div className="uk-flex uk-flex-column">
                    <nav className="uk-navbar-container" data-uk-navbar>
                        <div className="uk-navbar-left">
                            <a className="uk-navbar-item uk-logo" href="#"><img src={'images/logo.png'}/></a>

                            <ul className="uk-navbar-nav">
                                <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div className="uk-navbar-right">
                            <ul className="uk-navbar-nav">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" className="uk-open" aria-expanded="true">
                                        <span data-uk-icon="icon: user" />
                                    </a>

                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                    <div className="uk-flex-grow-1">
                        <Route path="/" component={Welcome} />
                    </div>
                    <footer>
                        &copy; 2018 stackoverflow.com
                    </footer>
                    <Message />
                </div>    
            </Router>
        );
    }

}

if (document.getElementById('root')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Index/>, document.getElementById('root'));
}
```

Ok, so the Index component is the one I start with. I import the Message component and render it. That works. In chrome react console, I select the Message tag and can add some messages with

> $r.setMessage('success','Greetings my old friend!')

The message appears. So now, how can I use the method setMessage in my Index component? In vue.js it's so simple (use $parent or $children)...

Comment: I see answers popping up mentioning refs, but before you get excited about them, I recommend you read https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Yeah you should avoid this bottom up dataflow in React and inverse it via passing messageArray to Message Component and handle this setMessage stuff in the Index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most direct way to access the methods of another component is to pass [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), but you should probably approach the issue in a different way. Once you start tying your components together with refs, you make them less reusable and more difficult to work with.

If the list of messages were stored at a higher level, and passed into your `Message` component as a prop, then you would have no need for refs.

So I would recommend moving `messages` into the state of the `Index` component (or possibly even to a store), then passing `messages` as a prop to `<Message messages={this.state.messages} />`.

If you also want to manipulate the messages from within the `Message` component, then also pass whatever callbacks from `<Index>` that you need.

Below is a toy example showing the general idea of storing the state in the parent component and passing `messages` and `addMessage` as props to `<Message>`.

```js
const Message = ({ messages, addMessage }) => (
  <div>
    {messages.map(({ text, id }) => <div key={id}>{text}</div>)}
    <button onClick={addMessage}>add</button>
  </div>
);

class Index extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addMessage = this.addMessage.bind(this);
  }

  state = {
    messages: [],
    id: 0
  };
  
  addMessage() {
    this.setState({ 
      messages: [...this.state.messages, { text: "new message", id: this.state.id }],
      id: this.state.id + 1
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return <Message messages={this.state.messages} addMessage={this.addMessage} />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Index/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `refs` to get the reference to the element e.g.

```
<Message refs={(ref) => this.messageElement = ref }/>
```

With that you can call methods on it from anywhere after it has been assigned

```
this.messageElement.setMessage();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use refs (references) as

```
 <Message ref={(c) => this.messageComponent = c} />
```

and make functions of `Message` component with context bound so that it is accessible in other components like

`Message` Component

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {messages: []};
        this.setMessage = this.setMessage.bind(this);
    }
```

Usage in `Index` component

```
  this.messageComponent.setMessage('type','body');
```

Read more of refs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)